# Js Dialog box close button not showng, but when click on blank square box it is closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery dialog box ui is working but close symbol not showing, however when it show only blank squre box, if click on it, it closes jquery dialog modal box.

i have changed the place of bootstrap cdn. when bootstrap 5.1.3 and 4.3.1 are removed, close button is shown on the dialog box. but if i remove bootstrap then my whole page not look good.
below are the codes that i have tried.

```html
<!-- chat js department -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<!-- ends here -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>
<script>
```

```js
function make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name, to_lead_id)
  {
  var modal_content = '<div id="user_dialog_'+to_user_id+'" class="user_dialog" title="'+to_user_name+'| Lead Id:'+to_lead_id+'">';
  modal_content += '<div style="height:340px; border:1px solid #ccc; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:24px; padding:16px;" class="chat_history" data-touserid="'+to_user_id+'" id="chat_history_'+to_user_id+'">';
  modal_content += '</div>';
  modal_content += '<div class="form-group">';
  modal_content += '<textarea placeholder="type your message here.." name="chat_message_'+to_user_id+'" id="chat_message_'+to_user_id+'" class="form-control chat_message"></textarea>';
  modal_content += '</div>';

  modal_content += '<div class="form-group" align="right">';
  modal_content+= '<button type="button" name="send_chat" id="'+to_user_id+'" data-leadid="'+to_lead_id+'" class="btn btn-info send_chat">Send</button></div></div>';
  $('#user_model_details').html(modal_content);
  }

$(document).on('click', '.start_chat', function()
  {
  var to_user_id   = $(this).data('touserid');
  var to_user_name = $(this).data('tousername');
  var to_lead_id   = $(this).data('toclientid');

  make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name,to_lead_id);

  $("#user_dialog_"+to_user_id).dialog(
    { autoOpen    : false
    , width       : 500
    , height      : 600
    , dialogClass : 'myTitleClass'
    , position    : 
      { my : "right top"
      , at : "right top+350"
      , of : window
      }
    });
  $('#user_dialog_'+to_user_id).dialog('open');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

// found solution: just simply added below codes:

var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict()

$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).